# How to enter the parameters on the command line for this shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I was setting up VMWare ESXi on my laptop for learning purposes. I wanted to automate things and got this very nice shell script. It asks for parameters such as the cpu cores, iso path, ram and disk space. I am a beginner in the shell. I understand that it's a very basic question but couldn't find an answer on the internet. Here's the code.

I don't understand how to enter the values of `<|c|i|r|s>` — the syntax required is not clear, to be precise.

```
#paratmers: machine name (required), CPU (number of cores), RAM (memory size in MB), HDD Disk size (in GB), ISO (Location of ISO image, optional)
#default params: CPU: 2, RAM: 4096, DISKSIZE: 20GB, ISO: 'blank'
-
phelp() {
    echo "Script for automatic Virtual Machine creation for ESX"
    echo "Usage: ./create.sh options: n <|c|i|r|s>"
    echo "Where n: Name of VM (required), c: Number of virtual CPUs, i: location of an ISO image, r: RAM size in MB, s: Disk size in GB"
    echo "Default values are: CPU: 2, RAM: 4096MB, HDD-SIZE: 20GB"
}

CPU=2
RAM=4096
SIZE=20
ISO="ISO'S"
FLAG=true
ERR=false
n=vmoo 


while getopts n:c:i:r:s: option
 do
    case $option in
            n)
                NAME=${OPTARG};
                FLAG=false;
                if [ -z $NAME ]; then
                    ERR=true
                    MSG="$MSG | Please make sure to enter a VM name."
                fi
                ;;
            c)
                CPU=${OPTARG}
                if [ `echo "$CPU" | egrep "^-?[0-9]+$"` ]; then
                    if [ "$CPU" -le "0" ] || [ "$CPU" -ge "32" ]; then
                        ERR=true
                        MSG="$MSG | The number of cores has to be between 1 and 32."
                    fi
                else
                    ERR=true
                    MSG="$MSG | The CPU core number has to be an integer."
                fi
                ;;
            i)
                ISO=${OPTARG}
                if [ ! `echo "$ISO" | egrep "^.*\.(iso)$"` ]; then
                    ERR=true
                    MSG="$MSG | The extension should be .iso"
                fi
                ;;
            r)
                RAM=${OPTARG}
                if [ `echo "$RAM" | egrep "^-?[0-9]+$"` ]; then
                    if [ "$RAM" -le "0" ]; then
                        ERR=true
                        MSG="$MSG | Please assign more than 1MB memory to the VM."
                    fi
                else
                    ERR=true
                    MSG="$MSG | The RAM size has to be an integer."
                fi
                ;;
            s)
                SIZE=${OPTARG}
                if [ `echo "$SIZE" | egrep "^-?[0-9]+$"` ]; then
                    if [ "$SIZE" -le "0" ]; then
                        ERR=true
                        MSG="$MSG | Please assign more than 1GB for the HDD size."
                    fi
                else
                    ERR=true
                    MSG="$MSG | The HDD size has to be an integer."
                fi
                ;;
            \?) echo "Unknown option: -$OPTARG" >&2; phelp; exit 1;;
            :) echo "Missing option argument for -$OPTARG" >&2; phelp; exit 1;;
            *) echo "Unimplimented option: -$OPTARG" >&2; phelp; exit 1;;
    esac
done

if $FLAG; then
echo "You need to at least specify the name of the machine with the -n parameter."
exit 1
fi

if $ERR; then
echo $MSG
exit 1
fi

if [ -d "$NAME" ]; then
echo "Directory - ${NAME} already exists, can't recreate it."
exit
fi


mkdir ${NAME}


vmkfstools -c "${SIZE}"G -a lsilogic $NAME/$NAME.vmdk


touch $NAME/$NAME.vmx


cat << EOF > $NAME/$NAME.vmx

config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "7"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
displayName = "${NAME}"
floppy0.present = "FALSE"
numvcpus = "${CPU}"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0.sharedBus = "none"
scsi0.virtualDev = "lsilogic"
memsize = "${RAM}"
scsi0:0.present = "TRUE"
scsi0:0.fileName = "${NAME}.vmdk"
scsi0:0.deviceType = "scsi-hardDisk"
ide1:0.present = "TRUE"
ide1:0.fileName = "${ISO}"
ide1:0.deviceType = "cdrom-image"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "32"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000"
ethernet0.networkName = "Inside"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
guestOS = "other26xlinux-64"
EOF


MYVM=`vim-cmd solo/registervm /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/${NAME}/${NAME}.vmx`

vim-cmd vmsvc/power.on $MYVM

echo "The Virtual Machine is now setup & the VM has been started up. Your have the    following configuration:"
echo "Name: ${NAME}"
echo "CPU: ${CPU}"
echo "RAM: ${RAM}"
echo "HDD-size: ${SIZE}"
if [ -n "$ISO" ]; then
echo "ISO: ${ISO}"
else
echo "No ISO added."
fi
echo "Thank you."
exit
```

Comment: Without the part of the script where it actually _parses_ the parameters, I don't know how we're supposed to help. The usage text is indeed ambiguously written.

Comment: Also, if you're asking how to *use* a script, as opposed to how to *write* a script, that's not really a question that's a good fit for StackOverflow; you might try SuperUser instead. Even then, though, they'll need the entire script.

Comment: sorry i had problems with editing else i would've done that in the beginning. i think my problem is not a complicated one.it asks you to enter the parameters like cpu core, iso path, ram,disk size .

Comment: sorry i had probs with editing. i did that anyway. btw my prob is a simple one i guess. all i want to know is, how do i pass the arguments such as ram,iso path , size of disk etc.

Comment: like sh create.sh -n ubuntu [cpucores][iso path] etc. i dont know the syntax ,i know i am a noob

Comment: The usage syntax is set by the person who made the script. Really, you should be talking to them, not to us. That said, from a quick reading, a simple guess is available.

Comment: BTW, `sh create.sh` is only necessary if the script isn't set executable or doesn't have a correct shebang. You should almost always be running `./create.sh` (or even better, `./create` without the file having an extension at all), which lets the file pick its own interpreter; that way, a script built to use bash, ksh, &c. will use those interpreters, instead of `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter them as `-k value` pairs, where `k` is the letter used to identify the parameter.

For instance:

```
./create.sh -n vmname -c 2 -i /path/to/file.iso -s 512
```

This sets the name to `vmname`, the number of CPUs to 2, the ISO filename to `/path/to/file.iso`, etc.

Comment: thanks man. that was what i needed . haha so silly of me, i was trying to test it on my local machine instead of ssh'ing to the esxi server

Answer (score 1):

The usage message is about as unhelpful as you can get and still make an attempt at conveying information. Without the code, I would not have known what to do.  Fortunately, with shell scripts, you can see the code, though.  The usage message should read something more like:

```
{
echo "Usage: $0 -n 'vm name' [-c cpus][-i iso-image][-r ram][-s disk]"
echo "  -n 'vm name'  Name of VM (required)"
echo "  -c cpus       Number of virtual CPUs"
echo "  -i iso-image  Location of an ISO image"
echo "  -r ram        RAM size in MB"
echo "  -s disk       Disk size in GB"
echo "Default values are: CPU: 2, RAM: 4096MB, HDD-SIZE: 20GB"
} >&2
```

Take heed: when you write a shell script, ensure that the usage information is clearly documented, either in the usage message or perhaps in comments within the script.  The shell script you show is an example of how not to do it.